# Prove that sequence $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \le r$ converges to $0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

This question is about the following:

> Let $(a_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ be the sequence of positive numbers.
>
> Let $r \in \mathbb{R} \, \wedge \, 0 < r < 1$
>
> $ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}_0 : \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \le r$
>
> Prove that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$

The sequence $a_n$ is bounded from below by $0$ because of its definition.

But I was not able to come up with an proof that the sequence $a_n$ converges to $0$.

Comment: Prove by induction that $a_n \leq r^n a_0$.

Comment: $a_2\leq a_1r$, $a_3\leq a_2r\leq a_1r^2$, ..., so $a_n\leq a_1r^{n-1}$. What does this tell you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a nice trick:

$$a_n=\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n-2}}\cdots\frac{a_2}{a_1}a_1.$$

Can you finish the rest from here?